# Is there a tool that can transform a web app to desktop app or mobile app, etc.?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, html, css

I have a 'blurry' memory that I once have seen a video where a developer wrote an app in HTMl, CSS, JS, PHP/Laravel and somehow transformed it into a desktop application.

**Is there a tool that can transform a web app written in HTML/CSS/JS AND PHP & Laravel, Python & Django or any other backend framework into desktop app or a mobile app?**

Comment: Hello, you need to be as **specific** as possible when asking questions on these websites. This question isn't too answerable. For example, is the whole backend supposed to be converted for the application to be offline or can it stay online just like it was? Desktop and mobile for which platforms, Windows, Linux, iOS? What kind of JS frameworks are in use? Is it pure CSS or do you use help of any preprocessors like SCSS? Etc. Details about your project are needed because it's definitely notas simple as just pressing a magic button and any sort of project gets converted the way you want it to.

Comment: You are thinking of PWAs (Progressive Web Apps).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One technology that does something similar is [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_Native). See other references to alternative technologies on the wikipedia page. But usually your Python/PHP backend remains as-is. It is not converted to a mobile app.

Comment: @RohitGupta thank you. Yes, I've heard of them but wasn't really informed about them. Lately I was digging more into the topic and now I know a little bit more about PWA.

Comment: @knb thank you for sharing about the backend

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), which also adds capabilities to the web scripts that allows it to manipulate files. For mobile support, you can use it with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/electron/) or just use [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) or [GoNative SelfServe](https://gonative.io/pricing#self-serve).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But why should I use Electron or any other framework you provided if I can just create a PWA? As far as I understand, I can create a website using any webframeworks, for example Vue.js. And then I can just transform it staright into the PWA which will work on any OS either desktop: Windows, Linux, MacOS or mobile: Android, iOS. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that to install a PWA an installed browser is required. Furthermore, I'm also pretty sure that PWAs require a web server to be set up, while the other frameworks I've mentioned can work with desktop files as long as you code it that way.